# Ruby eliminating object duplicates in arrays

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays

I'm working on merging three arrays while eliminating duplicates and wondering if there is a short way to do it. Lets say I've got 2 arrays containing person objects, which have `firstname` and `lastname` properties.

I now want to combine these two arrays to a new one, containing all unique persons. So there should only be one `John Doe` but `John Paul` and `Fred Paul` is ok. I hope the question is clear enough? Thanks!

Comment: When you say "containing all unique persons", do you mean "all unique records from my persons table" or do you mean "containing at most one person record for each unique name"?

Comment: If the data *does* come from the database, there is a good chance that 3 separate queries => merging => uniq can be replaced by just a combined DB query.

Comment: I mean `all unique records from my persons table`. The data comes from three different DBs, so I guess I can't do that combined query. But just because I'm now curious, how would that query look like?

Comment: No way if it's from different databases, but if it were to come from a single one, it'd be possible (although might not be straightforward in case of sophisticated queries). With more or less simple queries: `SELECT * FROM people WHERE a=1`, `SELECT * FROM people WHERE b=2`, and `SELECT * FROM people WHERE c=3`, you could have a single `SELECT * FROM people WHERE (a=1) OR (b=2) OR (c=3)`.

Comment: I see, thanks for the additional info. By the way, is there a way to eliminate duplicates without combining the arrays at it? E.g. A is B without C.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can concat the arrays and call `#uniq` on the resulting array:

```
(ary1 + ary2 + ary3).uniq { |person| [person.firstname, person.lastname] }
```

Alternatively, if the `Person` class implements the equality method `#==`, you can go just with this:

```
class Person
  # ...

  def ==(other)
    firstname == other.firstname && lastname == other.lastname
  end
end

(ary1 + ary2 + ary3).uniq
```

See [`Array#uniq`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Array.html#method-i-uniq).

Comment: Absolutely awesome, I knew there was a rubyish way to do it. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Can you just use the `Array#uniq` method?

http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Array.html#method-i-uniq

EDIT: sorry, missed the `three arrays` bit.   Let's say you've got all your arrays stored in a variable called '@arrays' then you can do

```
@arrays.inject{|a,b| a + b}.uniq
```

Or, if you'd rather something more specific to the names of the arrays

```
(@array1 + @array2 + @array3).uniq
```

Comment: Max, `arrays.inject{|a,b| a+b}` can be simplified to `arrays.inject(&:+)`

Comment: Not in my console it can't.

Comment: @GoshaArinich i beg your pardon:  it works in newer versions of ruby but not in older (in the older it expects two arguments).

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Array#|`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Array.html#method-i-7C) which performs set union. So, for three arrays `arr1`, `arr2`, `arr3`, then the set union is `arr1 | arr2 | arr3`.